# How to get data from database mysql with For clause in Vb net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a code on vb.net, I want to use looping for vb.net to retrieve data from the mysql database.

the problem that I face seems to repeat loop not working properly, the data obtained only repeats the first data ..

can anyone help me ??

```vb
conn.Open()
sqlConn1 = "select * from transaksi"
data3 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn1, conn)
data3.Fill(ds3, "transaksi")

Dim keterangan As String

Dim c4 As String = String.Empty
For c As Integer = 0 To ds3.Tables("transaksi").Rows.Count - 1

    sqlConn2 = "select * from transaksi"
    data32 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn2, conn)
    data32.Fill(ds32, "transaksi")

    c4 = ds32.Tables("transaksi").Rows(c).Item("idTransaksi")

    'For d As Integer = 0 To s - 1

    Dim nilaihasil As Double
    Dim nilaix As Double
    Dim var_a As Double
    Dim var_b As Double


    For f As Integer = 0 To 5 - 1
        sqlConn6 = "select * from transaksidetail WHERE idTransaksi = '" & c4 & "'"
        data6 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn6, conn)
        data6.Fill(ds6, "transaksidetail")

        var_a = ds6.Tables("transaksidetail").Rows(f).Item("nilaiTransaksidetail")

        sqlConn7 = "select nilai from cluster WHERE idKriteria = '" & ds6.Tables("transaksidetail").Rows(f).Item("idKriteria") & "' AND kode = 'C0'"
        data7 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn7, conn)
        data7.Fill(ds7, "cluster")
        var_b = ds7.Tables("cluster").Rows(f).Item("nilai")

        'MessageBox.Show(var_a & var_b)
        nilaix += ((var_a ^ 2) - (var_b ^ 2))

    Next

    nilaihasil = Math.Sqrt(nilaix)

    perintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    perintah.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tempcluster (idTemp,idTransaksi,nilai,cluster) VALUES ('','" & c4 & "','" & nilaihasil & "','C0')"
    perintah.Connection = conn
    perintah.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next c
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Your explanation is inadequate. Don't just tell us that you want to use a loop.  Explain EXACTLY what using that loop is supposed to achieve.  If the point is to populate a `DataTable` and then do something for each row then you should be using a `For Each` loop over the `Rows` collection.  As you can see, the code basically matches description of what is to be done, which is one of the main aims of VB syntax.

Comment: Can you provide some result or screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be refilling the DataTable transaksi inside the loop. Comments and explanation in line.

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("Your Connection String")
    conn.Open()
    Dim sqlConn1 = "select * from transaksi"
    Dim data3 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn1, conn)
    Dim ds3 As New DataSet
    data3.Fill(ds3, "transaksi")

    Dim keterangan As String = ""

    Dim c4 As String = String.Empty
    For c As Integer = 0 To ds3.Tables("transaksi").Rows.Count - 1
        'It looks like you are doing the same thing twice
        'Anyway, you don't want to do it over and over in the loop
        'sqlConn2 = "select * from transaksi"
        'data32 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn2, conn)
        'data32.Fill(ds32, "transaksi")

        c4 = ds3.Tables("transaksi").Rows(c).Item("idTransaksi").ToString


        Dim nilaihasil As Double
        Dim nilaix As Double
        Dim var_a As Double
        Dim var_b As Double

        Dim sqlConn6 = "select * from transaksidetail WHERE idTransaksi = '" & c4 & "'"
        Dim data6 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn6, conn)
        Dim ds6 As New DataSet
        data6.Fill(ds6, "transaksidetail")

        'This looks a little silly, how about To 4
        For f As Integer = 0 To 5 - 1
            'Move the following out of the loop
            'No sense doing the same thing 5 times
            'sqlConn6 = "select * from transaksidetail WHERE idTransaksi = '" & c4 & "'"
            'data6 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn6, conn)
            'data6.Fill(ds6, "transaksidetail")

            var_a = CDbl(ds6.Tables("transaksidetail").Rows(f).Item("nilaiTransaksidetail"))

            Dim sqlConn7 = "select nilai from cluster WHERE idKriteria = '" & ds6.Tables("transaksidetail").Rows(f).Item("idKriteria").ToString & "' AND kode = 'C0'"
            Dim data7 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn7, conn)
            Dim ds7 As New DataSet
            data7.Fill(ds7, "cluster")
            var_b = CDbl(ds7.Tables("cluster").Rows(f).Item("nilai"))

            'MessageBox.Show(var_a & var_b)
            nilaix += ((var_a ^ 2) - (var_b ^ 2))

        Next

        nilaihasil = Math.Sqrt(nilaix)
        Dim perintah As New MySqlCommand
        perintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        perintah.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tempcluster (idTemp,idTransaksi,nilai,cluster) VALUES ('','" & c4 & "','" & nilaihasil & "','C0')"
        perintah.Connection = conn
        perintah.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next c
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```